# css to replace an image

Tags: css, skinning

I am familiar with CSS techniques to replace text with an image. For example, here are 9 of them: http://css-tricks.com/nine-techniques-for-css-image-replacement/

Are there any techniques for replacing images? Is there anyway to set the background of an image to an image and then hide or move the foreground of the image (the image src element).

I am trying to write a skin for a site that has an image that I want to replace. Thanks.

> From how I understand it he's trying to do this in pure CSS, with no changes to HTML or JavaScript.

That is correct. I am adding a new stylesheet to an existing page. Let say I can not modify HTML or utilize javascript.

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense to me, can you rephrase? Background of an image to an image, specifically. An image is an single entity, you can stack two images on top of each other but you cannot selectively remove components of an image.

Comment: He wants to essentially change the <img>'s src with CSS. I've had to do this before, but unfortunately I don't remember how I ended up doing it...

Comment: @musicfreak: not sure what your problem with the answers posted is. Maybe Mike needs to post more details on the "situation" - are you saying you can't change any HTML content but can add a stylesheet to a page?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Yes, exactly. From how I understand it he's trying to do this in pure CSS, with no changes to HTML or JavaScript. If he updates his answer and I'm wrong, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little bit of tinkering, I figured it out!

```
img.someclass {
  background: url("NEW IMAGE URL") top right;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 200px 550px 0 0; /* Insert actual image size (height width 0 0) */
}
```

This will make the height and width of the actual image 0, but will expand the box to fill the size of the image with padding. The only downside to this is it won't look perfect in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Awesome, musicfreak. Here's a demo of it working for me…

http://www.screentoaster.com/watch/stU09VQkdIR11ZRlheXltbU1dS

Comment: Damn, your solution is good, way better than my second attempt (which does work but is unnecessarily complex).

Comment: DisgruntledGoat, still a good attempt. Thanks you and musicfreak for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an element surrounding the image, e.g. a DIV, you should be able to set a background image (along with no-repeat and a position) on it, then set the image to `display:none`.

Alternatively, here's a haphazard solution that seems to work. It positions the image off-screen, then uses the `:after` pseudo-element to set a background image. It should be workable, but you'll need to fiddle with the values to get it working right. It won't work in IE6 though.

```
<style>
  img.test {
    background: url('image_to_show.png') no-repeat right top;
    position: relative;
    left: -16000px;
  }
  img.test:after {
    content: ".";
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 16000px;
  }
</style>

<img class="test" src="image_to_hide.png">
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I wouldn't have thought about using :after. +1

Comment: Also, as a side note in case someone wants to use this approach, you should probably make it more than 500px to the left because of widescreen monitors with gigantic resolutions.

Comment: musicfreak, you're right; edited. Originally I did this assuming that it would only work if the original image was close to the edge of the canvas - because I didn't think I'd be able to "stretch" the element across other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to replace images is to set the background position. First create the two different images and put them one above the other in the same image. Say your skin element is 50x50 pixels, you'd create a 50x100 image.

Then use some code like this:

```
.skinElement1 {
  background: #fff url("image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
.skinElement2 {
  background: #fff url("image.png") no-repeat 0 -50px;
}
```

So to view the second image you move the background up by the required amount. You could either use javascript or your server-side code to set the appropriate class.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can set an opacity of an element and then set the background to the image you want.

Musicfreak: I meant using TWO elements.

Comment: Opacity affects the background, so that would make the background transparent as well.

Comment: @EFraim: Well the OP said he can't change the HTML. I didn't downvote you because it's still a good idea, though.

Answer (score -2):

you will have assign different classes for the two states then write some javascript to have the image change upon an event.

for example:

```
.firsImage { background:transparent url(/images/someImage.jpg) no-repeat; }
.secondIMage { background:transparent url(/images/image2.jpg) no-repeat; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imageDiv" class="firstImage"> some content </div>
<a onclick="changeImage()">Change the image!</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeImage(){
    var imageDiv =  document.getElementById("imageDiv")

    if ( imageDiv.className === "firsImage" )
        document.getElementById("imageDiv").className = "secondImage"
    else
        document.getElementById("imageDiv").className = "firstImage"
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want the src to change on an event, he wants to use CSS to change the image's src, essentially.